# Get row query from request API database

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, request, telegram-bot

Im making a telegram bot. I cant connect my API with telegram bot

```js
const request = require('request');
request('http://127.0.0.1/api/product/read.php', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    const h = JSON.parse(body);
    const t = h.title || '';

    hasil = h.records;
    console.log(hasil);
    console.log(h);
    // //  console.log(t);
  }
});

console.log('asd' + hasil);
console.log(h);
```

I want to get the result from the request API which is the row from my db. But I cant get the result outside the request function.

I actually want to make the output in telegram bot. since the telegram bot function cant be used inside the request function.

So I'm thinking to get the result from the request. But I cant get the result outisde the function.

```
console.log(hasil); // the output is here
console.log('asd'+hasil); // but this is nothing.
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

What you need is a global variable and a await statement to make the async process synchronous.

```
let hasil = undefined; //Global variable that you can access anywhere.
const request = require('request');
await request('http://127.0.0.1/api/product/read.php', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    const h = JSON.parse(body);
    const t = h.title || '';

    hasil = h.records;
    console.log(hasil);
    console.log(h);
    // //  console.log(t);
  }
});

console.log('asd' + hasil);
console.log(h);
```

However, I will warn you that global variables are generally frowned upon.
Here's why: http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad

A useful link to learn about global variables: https://stackabuse.com/using-global-variables-in-node-js/

Useful link to learn about await and asynchrony: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: This won't work as request is async and is basically the same as OP's code.

Comment: @h77 I believe I have revised the code to work, could you please reconsider giving me a downvote?

Comment: I don't think request returns a Promise therefore it might not be awaitable.